# Explanation on the steps of this total arc-length solution

Tags: parametric, arc-length

Can someone please explain to me what rules have been used to calculate ${\bf{\dot{x}}}$ and $|{\bf{\dot{x}}}|$ in the definition for total arc-length of this problem. I've tried to calculate this by expanding everything out, but get lost in the workings. Has the identity $\cos^2t+\sin^2t=1$ been used to eliminate $\cos$ and $\sin$?

**Example:** Calculate the total length of the following curve.

The logarithmic spiral, $x=e^{−ωt}$ $(R\cos2πt, R\sin2πt)$ with ω > 0 and $R > 0$ constants and I = [0,∞).

**Solution:**

The total length is

\begin{align}
L &=\int_0^∞ 
Re^{−ωt}(ω^2 + 4π^2)^{1/2} dt\\
&=
\frac{R}{ω} (ω^2 + 4π^2)^{1/2}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$L = \int \|\frac {d\mathbf x}{dt}\| \ dt$

$\frac {d}{dt} \mathbf x = -\omega e^{-\omega t}(R\cos 2\pi t,R\sin 2\pi t) + e^{-\omega t}(-2\pi R\sin 2\pi t,2\pi R\cos 2\pi t)$

The two terms are orthogonal to one another.

$\|\frac {d\mathbf x}{dt}\|^2 = \|-\omega R e^{-\omega t}(\cos 2\pi t,\sin 2\pi t)\|^2 + \|2\pi Re^{-\omega t}(-\sin 2\pi t,\cos 2\pi t)\|^2$

$\|\frac {d\mathbf x}{dt}\| =Re^{-\omega t}\sqrt{\omega^2+(2\pi)^2}  $

Comment: Thank you. That cleared my confusion :)